# Bad signs from HR during recruiting

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I am getting some bad signs from the company I am got an offer from:

- the head of HR answers emails late at night
- she also almost forgot about a meeting with me and arrived 20 minutes late
- she proposed to me a modification of the contract to then retract it, as she was not aligned with some superior

I will not be working in HR but in a technical department.

> How much should I worry about these signs?

Comment: To everyone who downvotes, please comment on ways that my question can be improved to better fit the community guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

They are human, sometimes they forget. Sometimes their superiors override them.  Some work late at night like me.  It's my most productive time.

Don't worry about the "signs". Just concentrate on getting the best deal for you.

Answer (score 2):

So you have figured out the HR at this company is somewhat disorganized.

> How much should I worry about these signs?

Since you are not working in HR that is not going to affect you much directly in your day to day work. The key question here is the following: Is this just HR (or just this one person in HR) or this indicative of the broader company culture.

Hopefully you have checked on this during the interview process with your hiring manager and other technical interviewers. If you went over the work processes, metrics and culture and that feels good to you, than you are most likely in the clear here.

If you did NOT talk about this during the interview, it would probably be a good idea read online reviews or check up on other sources. Possibly you may be able to schedule another Q&A session with the hiring manager (but that requires a fair bit of diplomacy).

Remember that interviewing is a two way street: the questions that you ask are as important than they question that you get asked. You want to make sure you don't end up in place that's disorganized and chaotic or otherwise incompatible with your goals, culture and preferences.